# Diagnostics warning for "Decision Runner Resource Provider" for Business Rules on Bluemix

Tags: business-rules, ibm-cloud

When running the Diagnostics for the Rule Execution Server for the Business Rules instance on Bluemix, I see the following warning:

```
 Decision Runner Resource Provider     
 Warning     
 Diagnostic failed 
 Run the installation wizard to create database tables
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this question is already answered in the [IBM developer forum](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/184488/diagnostics-warning-for-decision-runner-resource-p.html).

Excerpt from the link :
This warning is expected for the Business Rules service on Bluemix, and can be safely ignored. You will see it if your instance uses the version Decision Server 8.7.0.1. (See the About section in the Rule Execution Server console).

Hope it helps.